# Load Modules failed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I used Chrome to open the index.html page and the error is cannot find right modules.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < controller.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < service.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.js:1
```

I used Firefox and got the following similar errors

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'


<html ng-app="todo">

angular.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'


<html ng-app="todo">

controller.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'


<html ng-app="todo">

service.js (line 1)
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'


<html ng-app="todo">

main.js (line 1)
```

I have been finding out where I made mistakes for a while, but still no clues. I copied and pasted the code here and thanks in advance for pointing me out.
Code is as bellow shows:

service.js file

```
var service = angular.module("service",[]);

service.factory("todoFactory", ["$http",
    function($http){
        return {
            get: function(){
                return $http.get('/todo');
            },
            create: function(newtodo){
                return $http.post('/todo', newtodo);
            },
            delete: function(id){
                return $http.delete('/todo:' + id);
            }
        }
}]);
```

controller.js file

```
var ctrl = angular.module("controller", []);
ctrl.controller("mainController", ['$http', '$scope', 'todoFactory', function($scope, $http, todoFactory){
    $scope.formData = {};


    todoFactory.get().success(function(data){
        $scope.todoitems = data;
    });


    if(!$scope.formData.title && !$scope.formData.content){
        //var newtodoData = {
        //    "title":$scope.formData.title,
        //    "content" : $scope.formData.content
        //}
        todoFactory.create($scope.formData)
                   .success(function(data){
                        //return the updated todoitems
                        $scope.todoitems = data;
                        //clear form data for next time use
                        $scope.formData = {};
                    });
    }

}]);
```

main.js file

```
angular.module("todo", ["controller", "service"]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="todo">
    <head>
        <script src="frontend/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="frontend/controller.js"></script>
        <script src="frontend/service.js"></script>
        <script src="frontend/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="submitForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
                Title:
                <input class="form-control col-md-4" type="text" ng-model="formData.title"><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Content:
                <input class="form-control col-md-6" type="text" ng-model="formData.content"><br>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>

        <div>
            <p>Here is your todo list:</p>
                <div ng-repeat="item in todoitems"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">{{item.title}}</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">{{item.content}}</div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

## Following is my server side code

server.js

```
//set up all the modules needed
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var morgan = require("morgan");

var app = express();
var todoModel = require('./model.js');

//use part for middle layers
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                          
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));             
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                      
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

var port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
require('./route.js')(app);

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Route.js in backend

```
var todoModel = require('./model.js');


function getAllTodos(res){
    todoModel.find(function(err, alltododata){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(alltododata);
    });
}

module.exports = function(app){

    //render the view page
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('B:\\node\\ToDo\\NodeTODOMongo\\index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    });


    //get all todos return json data
    app.get('/todo', function(req, res){
        getAllTodos(res);
    });


    //create items and send back all todos after creation
    app.post('/todo', function(req, res){
        todoModel.create({
            title : req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content
        }, function(err, todo){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            getAllTodos(res);
        });
    });


    app.delete('/todo:id', function(req, res){
        todoModel.remove({
                _id : req.params.id
            }, //what is the alltodo here?
            function(err, todo){
                if(err)
                    res.send(err);
                getAllTodos(res);
            });
    });
}
```

**model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to localhost default test db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;

//let me know if the connection errors out
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));


db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});

//define schema of the todo model
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    createDate: {type: Date, default:Date.now}
});

var model = mongoose.model("todo", schema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("todo", schema);
```

Comment: can you upload main.js file somewhere?

Comment: @NikhilBhandari  Thanks for reply. main.js file only contains one line of code. I've already put that in the code snippet.

Comment: I just wanted to see the file, sometimes there are invisible characters that get copied when you copy something from a web page. I tried running your code and it worked on my machine so its not your code its either some invisible character or infected browser/machine . :)

Comment: Try the opening it in a different browser.

Comment: I tried using both Firefox and Chrome and got the same results......

Comment: Your controller module depends on the `todoFactory` from the service module, so it should declare it as a dependency: `angular.module("controller", ["service"])`.

Comment: @AustinMullins Nope. I just tried out, and it didn't work...

Comment: I didn't think that was the source of the error message you showed, but it was the next problem you would run into. It's really weird that you get that exact message on line 1 of every file. Are you sure there are no extra characters in those files?

Comment: @AustinMullins Yes, I copied and pasted directly from my source code editor. I don't think there are any extra characters. I thought it's module/dependency injection issues, but cannot hit exactly the point...

Comment: where are these files coming from? this looks like your server is mis-configured.  did you attempt to enable html5Mode and do rewrites? because it looks like when you request your js files, for example  `frontend/angular.js` from the server, you are getting back your `index.html` file, thus "expected expression, got `<html ng-app="todo">`", which is the first line of your `index.html`

Comment: @Claies I posted my server side code for your reference. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `app.get('*', function(req, res) {` in your node server is the problem here.  Basically, you have told the server that no matter what request comes in, it should return `res.sendfile('B:\\node\\ToDo\\NodeTODOMongo\\index.html');`.  This results in requests for your `.js` files causing the server to return `index.html` instead of the actual file requested.

You can add `app.use('/frontend', express.static(__dirname + '/frontend'));` before your `app.get` to enable a static request pipeline for the `/frontend` directory, which appears to be where your `.js` files are stored.

As pointed out by @GregL, you will also have issues with the other routes you have defined after the `app.get('*',...`.

I would recommend Bran Ford's [blog post](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express) on correctly configuring angular + express.

Comment: In other words, Express evaluates what route to run based on the order you specify routes in your code. By specifying a route which matches every GET request first, it doesn't matter what other `.get()` routes you define later, this first one will handle it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understand it now and it does help me. @GregL